# How to link data which points existing DBSet sources on Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an Interface. 
I have 2 class derived from this interface.
I want to make a list which contains all of this objects which derived same Interface.

So , can make a list and add seperate DbSet items to there. But there is some memory problem can happen.

So is there any way make a List from existing DbSet contents like linking soruces  ? Or how can i search this subject, which term ?

```
Interface IObject
{
int Id {get;set;}
string A {get;set;}
string B {get;set;}
string TypeName {get;set;}
}
```

Class 1

```
Class AObject:IObject
{
int Id {get;set;}
string A {get;set;}
string B {get;set;}
string TypeName {get;set;}
}
```

Class 2

```
Class BObject:IObject
{
int Id {get;set;}
string A {get;set;}
string B {get;set;}
string TypeName {get;set;}
}

public DbSet<AObject> AObjects{get;set;}
public DbSet<BObject> AObjects{get;set;}
```

I Want to make a List and return or query all of this DbSet contents as a single source from web api, and offer required results.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
List<IObject> response = ctx.AObjects.ToList()
                             .Cast<IObject>()
                             .Concat(ctx.BObjects.ToList()).ToList();
```

where ctx is the instance your your DbContext class

There currently is no way to query against an interface in EF.

You could however do something like:

```
public static class IObjectExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IObject> PeformQuery<T>(
                              this DbSet<T> set, 
                              Func<IObject,bool> @where) 
        where T : class, IObject
    {
        return set.Where(@where).AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

Used like:

```
Func<IObject, bool> q = item => item.Id < 2;
List<IObject> results = ctx.AObjects.PeformQuery(q).Concat(ctx.BObjects.PeformQuery(q)).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, it works like that. But does it make some memory problems ? For example, when we try to query to "response" as you described, if result count is 0 , there is already all data going into memory because of ToList().  If there is no problem, i will use it. Do you know, is there any way to define dynamic proxie between types which derived same interface ?

Comment: Calling ToList on an empty query should not cause memory problems... Unfortunately querying using an interface is not possible yet in EF. However you can use a generic method ^ But you have to evaluate the query, prior to combining them.